# Eclipse- How to include lib from lib/jars folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar

So my Ivy resolver is set to break things into type/name.jar   However that means that when I go to import something it doesn't seem to see it since it's apparently looking in /lib and not /lib/jars for the imports

How do I change the classpath to look at /lib/jars by default rather than something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chose

`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path`

from your menu and add libraries from your lib/jars folder

[image: Build Path]

Comment: Is there any way to make this the default over the /lib directory?